# Android ListView OnItemSelectedListenerが反応しない

Tags: android

OnItemSelectedListenerが反応しません。

- AdapterのisEnabledはtrueを返す
- 項目にはImageView一つとTextView一つ
- ListViewのchoiceModeはsingleChoice

考えられる原因はありますでしょうか？

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val listview = findViewById(R.id.listview) as ListView
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1)
    listview.adapter = adapter
    adapter.addAll("為吾郎", "熊乃介", "ヘンダーソンさん")
    listview.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override  fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
            print("selected")
        }

        override  fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ソースコードを追加すると回答がつきやすくなりますよ。

Comment: ありがとうございます。新しくプロジェクトを作ってソースコードを追加してみました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListView`において、`OnItemSelectedListener`はハードキーボードやトラックボールのある端末で、アイテムがフォーカスされたときに呼び出されます。

タップで選択されたアイテムを取得するリスナは、`OnItemClickListener`になります。

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val listView = findViewById(R.id.listView) as ListView
        listView.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout. simple_list_item_1, listOf("A", "B", "C", "D"))
        listView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->
            Log.d("debug", "click position in ${adapterView.adapter.getItem(i)}")
        }
    }
}
```

`ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE`を指定されているとのことで、例えばチェックボックスなどで単一選択を行う`ListView`を実装したいと考えているのかもしれません。

このとき、リストの各行のビューは`Checkable`インターフェースに準拠している必要がありますので、`simple_list_item_single_choice`を使うのが良いと思います。

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val listView = findViewById(R.id.listView) as ListView
        listView.choiceMode = ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
        listView.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, listOf("A", "B", "C", "D"))
    }
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
今作っているアプリではonItemClickListener を使うようにします。